# If $f(z_0)=0$ then can we say the $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}|1/f(z)| \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose f is analytic on $D_r(z_0)$. If $f(z_0)=0$ then can we say the $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0}|1/f(z)| \rightarrow \infty $? I suppose this should be correct but I am not 100% confident. Any help will be helpful thanks

Comment: If $f$ doesn't vanish identically, then it's unambiguously right. If $f\equiv 0$, then you have to decide how you handle $1/0$, you can either say $\lim_{z\to z_0} \lvert 1/f(z)\rvert$ doesn't make sense then, or you can say that it's $\infty$.

Comment: If $f=0$ then the expression is undefined, otherwise $z_0$ is an isolated zero and the limit is what you expected above.

Comment: Bingo. ${}{}{}$

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes true this will make sense if it is non zero in some punctured plane thanks

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks you..

Comment: You are uncertainly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct. If $f$ is analytic (and not identically zero) in a neighborhood of $z_0$. then $f(z)^{-1} = (z-z_0)^{-m}g(z)$ in some smaller neighborhood of $z_0$, where $g$ is analytic and non zero there. That is sufficient to imply that $\lim_{z \to z_0} |f(z)|^{-1} = \infty$.

Comment: @Jonas - Thank you, I fixed it.